# git-svn fetch authorization failure

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to clone an svn repository with git, but I get an authorization failure on the fetch step.  I'm only trying to get the trunk of the project currently:

```
$ git svn clone svn://some/repo --trunk=svn://some/repo/trunk/project/ --username afoglia .
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/afoglia/projects/new_repo/trunk.git/project/.git/
Using higher level of URL: svn://some/repo/trunk/project => svn://some/repo
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 100, path '/trunk/project'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Authorization failed: Authorization failed at /home/afoglia/.local/stow/git-1.7.7/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 3099
```

I've tried fetching only the most recent revisions, and that fails with the same message.

git is successfully accessing the repository in the first step; I can see the counter of revisions incrementing as it approaches the first revision with this directory.  So I don't know why there is a failure.  Note that the layout is multiple projects under a single trunk directory, and I only have permissions to read that project and below.

I'm unfamiliar with Perl, but line 3099 is an unless with a different die message, and the string "Authorization failed" is nowhere in the script.

Also, I had to install git under my own account, and compile and install svn as well, so this might be the result of a missing perl library.  (But I have successfully cloned an unsecured svn repository, so it's not something obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

First, `--trunk` accepts subdir, not absolute url. Next, you should provide `--parent` to get the most revision only. Try this way

```
git svn clone --username afoglia --parent svn://some/repo --trunk=trunk/project/ project-git
```

If it doesn't work try this way

```
git svn clone --username afoglia --parent svn://some/repo/trunk/project/ project-git
```

Comment: git svn clone doesn't like the "--parent" option.  `Unknown option: parent`.  So I tried doing an `git svn init` (which works) and then `git svn fetch --parent`.  That fails with the error `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD':...`, which makes sense because with nothing fetched, git has no HEAD from which to get the parent.  Also, I had first tried trunk with the subdir trunk/project.  There was no difference.  I switched to the full URL (which the man page explicitly says is supported) in unlikely case the two-level trunk subdir was the cause.

Comment: sorry, try `git clone -r HEAD` instead of `git clone --parent`